# Filter Algolia search result by external data

Tags: javascript, jquery, algolia

I am using Algolia vanilla instantsearch.js to get the results of a search on a Laravel 5.4 platform.

Now i am doing a prefered result feature where an use can save to db some of the records retreived by search. Until i have to select a record an save it it is ok and in the search page i can load an array with the IDs of records saved by user.

I need now a function to change the class of a record if it is in the preferred IDs array, something like:

```
if(in_array(this.id,IDs_array) change css class...
```

and i am using this Jquery function:

```
$(".myclass").each(function() {
....
});
```

But i am stuck because this function doesn't find the Algolia records.

So, i am asking, when the Algolia instantsearch results are loaded into document and how can i get them?